# Is it good to define all the constants in one file or in header file of the class being used in?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In Objective C, is it a good practice to define all the constants in one Constanst.h file or putting constants in .h file of the classes where they are used.

What is the general convention ?

**For example**:

Shall I define enums used in a custom view in the .h file of the view or in one central file.
Also in cases where I have Constants for hostname and routes for APIs, this should be in the module of the class interfacing with API  or again in the central file.

Comment: This is gonna raise different opinions. Personally I group things by FUNCTIONS, not by their DATA TYPES. That they're all constants doesn't mean they have to be near each other, or in the same file. Just put them where they belong to.

Comment: If its that much opinionated, Can anyone Move it to programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a Constants.h/.m file for the constants that are **shared by multiple classes**. (e.g constants about NSUserDefaults or NSNotificationCenter)

For the constants that are needed only **in one class** I define them into the class. (e.g. CELL_HEIGHT)

Morover, you could actually use a Constants.h and import it in Name-Prefix.pch so it will be automatically imported into all classes.

Comment: +1 I do exactly the same

Comment: You could actually use a Constants.h and import it in Name-Prefix.pch so it will be automatically imported into all classes.

Comment: +1 @soryngod I added it to my answer